# Catching special characters and accented characters

Tags: javascript, magento, prototype

I'm currently putting the finishing touches to our new Magento store, and it has come to light that I need to restrict the characters used in customers names and addresses.
This is all because of Royal Mail and their "dmo". I have my site set to print shipping labels out automatically using their "on demand" feature, and if it finds an illegal character it causes it to reject the entire address, however a tracking number still gets sent to the recipient!!!

So because of Royal Mail's wisdom I have to iron this out before it passes to them, and the easiest way is to prevent it at input.

I've added a custom.js to the validation already used in magento and added this:

```
['validate-strictalphanumericmustfill',                                                      //class name  



 'This input field can only contain A-Z, 0-9 and include spaces commas and full stops, and cannot be left blank. No special characters or Accents can be used',  //Error message to the user

                         function (v) {

 return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[A-Za-z\d\s]+$/.test(v)  //validation of input, 'v' being the input.

                         }

                        ]

                       ])
```

If the field is left empty it works, and displays my custom message, however it doesn't catch anything else.

Could somebody help correct my code please?

Thank you

Comment: Btw you regex include neither comma nor full stop, even though they are allowed according to error message.

Comment: Thanks, well spotted.
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9., ]+$   <<Would this be more suitable??

Comment: I changed my code to this and kept the original class also to check for empty fields

     return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9., ]+$/.test(v)  //validation of input, 'v' being the input. 

Thanks to kirilloid for spotting I had missed . and , out too :D